# How to check if Button Shapes is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

How do I check, using UIAccessibility, if the Button Shapes option in the iOS device accessibility settings is enabled? I want to support that 'button style' on a custom made button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441436/5544222) post to Swift:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIAccessibility {

    public static var isButtonShapesEnabled: Bool {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Button Shapes", for: .normal)
        return button.titleLabel?.attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) != nil
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
if UIAccessibility.isButtonShapesEnabled {
    // Apply button shapes style to custom button...
}
```